# How to define a static variable in a Module?

Tags: ocaml

so basically I am trying to define a static (global) variable in a `module`.

I used to use `class` a lot when programming in `OCaml`. And now when I try to use `Module` system, I just figure out I don't know how to define a static (global) variable in `OCaml`.. Shame on me..

Here is an example:

```
module Util = struct

  let l = ref [] 

  let get_l = 
      !l
  let set_l x =
     l := x::!l

end

open Util 

let () =
  let () = set_l 1 in
  let () = set_l 2 in
  print_int (List.length get_l)
```

IMHO, re-call function `set_l` would create a new instance of `l`, which is not what I need..

Could anyone give me some guide on defining a `static` variable in `module`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IMHO, re-call function set_l would create a new instance of l, which is not what I need..

Your intuition is incorrect.

```
l := x :: !l
```

Will prepend an `x` to a current value of `l`, and assign this newly created value to `l`, which is actually a pointer.

No new instances will be created.

The problem in your code, is in the `get_l`. It will be evaluated just after `let l = ref []` definition. E.g., at the point of time, when `l` is still empty. That means, that you need to delay the dereferencing to the point of time, when the value is really needed. So, what you really want is the following:

```
let get_l () = 
  !l
```

And

```
let () =
  let () = set_l 1 in
  let () = set_l 2 in
  print_int (List.length (get_l ()))
```

Now, `get_l ()` will dereference an `l` reference only after you've done this two assignments.

Comment: @computereasy this is not a bug of ocaml! In one case `get_l` is simply a value (which is computed when you define it) and is immutable, so it shouldn't give you an updated `l`. The version of @ivg is using a function which can lookup the current value pointed by `l`.